# Moving Swift struct definition to a different file causes build to fail

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, decodable

I'm implementing a parser utilizing structs and generic protocols to cut down on boilerplate, but I'm running into a really subtle bug related to how I organize my source code!

I want to parse some basic types like this

```
// some inner type
struct Foo {
    let x: Int
}
```

Inner types can be contained in various kinds of containers, but I want all containers to be able to give me an array of inner types:

```
// some containers contain an array
protocol MultiContainer {
    associatedtype Inner // XXX
    var objects: [Inner] { get }
}

// some containers contain a single object, which is a special case
protocol SingleContainer: MultiContainer { // XXX
    associatedtype Inner
    var object: Inner { get }
}

// this makes the single container conform
extension SingleContainer {
    var objects: [Inner] { return [object] }
}
```

Then the concrete container type looks like this:

```
struct SingleFooContainer: SingleContainer {
    let object: Foo
}

func test() {
    SingleFooContainer(object: Foo(x: 0)).objects
}
```

And all of this works perfectly if I put all of that in a single Swift file!

**BUT** if I move `SingleFooContainer` to a different source file (same directory/target as the other file), it fails to build (both in Xcode 10 and 11.2). Note that you have to leave the `test` func in the file with the protocol definitions.

It says

> Type 'SingleFooContainer' does not conform to protocol 'MultiContainer'
>
> Type 'SingleFooContainer' does not conform to protocol 'SingleContainer'

and if I have it insert protocol stubs it adds

```
typealias Inner = <#type#>
```

It's like there's a circular dependency between the two files that Swift can't figure out. Is this some gotcha about generic extensions that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you check whether the target of the new file is same as the old one.

Comment: @ParthaG yep, same target. I also tried reimplementing this in a new single page app, so there's only one target. I get the same error

Comment: I did create a new project on Xcode 11.1, add two swift files, one with protocols and one with the structs. Every time the project is built successfully. Did you clean a build folder? There sometimes are strange issues when Xcode indexing can't keep up

Comment: @kodelit I narrowed it down further. You have to try to use the structs in the same file as the generics e.g. put a call to `SingleFoobarContainer(object: Foobar(href: "a")).getObjects()` in the same file as the protocols.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the Swift compiler: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11806

Installing the latest trunk Swift toolchain in Xcode fixes the build error.